# What is the best algorithm to get maximum total value in binary tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I have some questions about getting maximum sum value in binary tree.

[image]

> Each node can have two child nodes (Left, Right)

> Sum[7, 3, 8, 7, 5] is the maximum sum value for the example above.

First, I thought choosing each max child node is best answer, but it is not.

```py
triangle = [[7], [3, 8], [8, 1, 0], [2, 7, 4, 4], [4, 5, 2, 6, 5]]
depth = 0
total = []

N = triangle[0][0]
```

```py
def min_max(depth, N, total):
    if (depth+1) == len(triangle):
        return total
    else:
        a,b = triangle[depth+1][triangle[depth].index(N)], triangle[depth+1][triangle[depth].index(N)+1]
        total.append(max(a,b))
        N = max(a,b)
        return min_max(depth+1, N, total)
```

```
min_max(depth, N, total) # [8, 1, 7, 5]
```

Then, I thought getting all cases sum and comparing, but it seems to worsen the time complexity.

What is the proper algorithm for this task?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: @SharimIqbal 
In case, `[7, 3, 8, 7, 5]` is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is; a simple, recursive way to calculate the sum for a node's children should be enough.

```py
def get_max(node):
    if not node:
        return 0
    return node.value + max(get_max(node.left), get_max(node.right))
```

Each node is visited only once, so this will have a complexity of `O(number of nodes) = O(N)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the maximum sum of a path from the root of the tree to any child. With a minimax algorithm, you can acheive a time complexity of roughly `O(2^N)`, where `N` is the depth of the tree.

However, I have here an `O(N^2)` dynamic programming solution to your problem, where `N` is the depth of the tree, and therefore `O(N^2)` is the scale of the number of nodes in the tree.

Define `dp[i]` to be the maximum sum of a path from the root of the tree to node `i`. Your base case is `dp[root] = value of the root node`. Iterate through the nodes from top to bottom (so root to child), and the dp function is

```
dp[node] = value_of_node[node]+max(dp[top_left_of[node]], dp[top_right_of[node]]);
```

Hopefully this is intuitive: the maximum sum of a path to a certain node has to come from either its top left or top right node.

Your answer is the maximum of all the `dp` values of the children of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle in the OP's post is a DAG (directed acyclic graph) while the recursive solution (posted by Abhinav Mathur) traverses it like a BT (binary tree) of the same height. So for the recursive solution to be O(N), N must be the number of nodes in the BT, not in the DAG. If N instead is the height of the BT (same as the DAG), the complexity becomes O(2^N) (as stated by Ryan Chang).

Since the triangle is a DAG, I suppose it is possible to reformulate the problem as Finding the Longest Path in a DAG (with the numbers in the triangle thought of as distances). It has linear complexity in the number of vertices and edges, O(V+E). That probably is the best one can do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is equal to finding a path that has the maximum sum.
The path must start from the root and end with a leaf node.

If the input is the root node of the binary tree, the answer is easy to figure out.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val: int, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def max_sum_path(root: Node) -> int:
    """

    :param root: Node
    :return: the max path sum
    """
    if not root:
        return 0
    return root.val + max(max_sum_path(root.left), max_sum_path(root.right))
```

If the input is the triangle(list). we can build the tree first.

```
# create node from each element
triangle = [[7], [3, 8], [8, 1, 0], [2, 7, 4, 4], [4, 5, 2, 6, 5]]
triangle_nodes = []
for level_val_lst in triangle:
    node_lst = [Node(e) for e in level_val_lst]
    triangle_nodes.append(node_lst)

# create tree
levels = len(triangle)
for level in range(levels - 1):
    node_lst = triangle_nodes[level]
    next_node_lst = triangle_nodes[level + 1]
    cnt_nodes = len(node_lst)
    for i, node in enumerate(node_lst):
        left_index = i
        right_index = i + 1
        node.left = next_node_lst[left_index]
        node.right = next_node_lst[right_index]
root = triangle_nodes[0][0]

res = max_sum_path(root)
print(res)
```